# Fastest approach to run an executable multiple times from python

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, process, subprocess

I am executing an external executable from python using the `subprocess` module. And every time i am sending the input to the executable using the `communicate( )` method of subprocess.

```
self.handler = subprocess.Popen([exec_file] , stdout=subprocess.PIPE , stdin=subprocess.PIPE) ; 
self.handler.communicate(self.input_string.encode()) ;
```

Apparently i want execute the same exe for thousands to hundreds of thousands of times for my project. What's the fastest or best way to do this

- I want to send input to it and not worry about output .
- I want to execute it many times and the input keeps changing every time.

Comment: Do you have the source code for the executable?  Seems it would be preferable to get it to loop itself.

Comment: ya ofcouse i have done the same , but what i want is a fastest optimised one , i think there might be a better way to do this ? I am trying to get the time taken by the program to give the output . So , anything which helps to reduce the time spent on things other than the time for processing the input i give , is helpful .

Comment: Please don't use indian words like 'lakh'

Answer (score 0):

Consider using coroutines from the asyncio library with the [create_subprocess_exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html#asyncio.create_subprocess_exec) function.